# Can multiple instances of AnsibleModule be created/called inside one Module?

Tags: python, python-2.7, ansible, ansible-2.x

Our server logical structure is based on the concept of "cluster" and "instance". A cluster is a set of instances of Weblogic and/or Karaf and/or Apache and/or Nginx and/or Jboss. The instances "MAY or MAY-NOT" be spread across multiple hosts.

A classic cluster would be:
hosts: a, b
Instances on a: tst13-apache, tst13-weblogic-ecom, tst13-weblogic-fulfill 
Instances on b: tst13-karaf-rest-bus, tst13-karf-rest-svcs, tst13-nginx-cache

I have created a super-class module (myMod) and 5 subclasses (myApache, myNginx, myJboss, myKaraf, myWeblogic). The "instance" information (inventory variables) are kept in an ldap database. The instances are not "registered" in rc.d directories on the hosts. Each server has "generic scripts" for starting an apache instance and a weblogic instance and a JBoss instance and ... by "instance name" so calling Ansible modules such as "httpd" was not practical.

My module will be used for "stop, start, status, kill, etc" (actions) taken against a list of instances.

Ideally, I would like to create an ssh connection to the destination "host" for EACH instance of software that is to be actioned on the destination host (which I believe would mean an instance of a module per instance of server-software that needs an action taken); however, thus far, it seems ansible makes 1 ssh connection per destination "host".

Since a "host" can be running many instances of different types of software (2 apache instances, 4 weblogic instances, and 3 karaf instances could all be on 1 host); it seemed practical to create my "myMod" as follows:

```
#####
## <ANSIBLE_HOME>/modules/controller.py    
#####
    import socket
    from ansible.module_utils.ldapData import ldapData
    from ansible.module_utils.myMod import myMod
    from ansible.module_utils.myModules import myApache, myNginx, myWeblogic, myKaraf, myJboss

    def main():

        arg_spec = dict(
                action = dict(default='status', choices=['start', 'stop', 'kill', 'status', 'warm', 'startsession', 'stopsession']),
                instances = dict(default='@', required=False, type='str'),
            )

        host = socket.gethostname()

        serverdata = ldapData()
        cluster = serverdata.hosts[host]["cluster"]
        clusterData = serverdata.clusters[cluster]
        hostData = serverdata.hosts[host]

        classList = list(myMod.__subclasses__())

        for classType in classList:
            localMod = classType(arg_spec, hostData, clusterData)
            localMod.process()

    if __name__ == '__main__':
        main()
```

The process method in myMod looks like this:

```
#####
## <ANSIBLE_HOME>/module_utils/myMod.py
#####
    def process(self):
        fPointers = {
                'start': self.start,
                'stop': self.stop,
                'kill': self.kill,
                'status': self.status,
                'stopsession': self.stopsession,
                'startsesson': self.startsession,
                'warm': self.warm
        }
        act = self.params['action']
        for inst in self.instances:
                if fPointers[act]:
                        fPointers[act](inst)
                else:
                        undefined(inst)
        self.exit_json(changed=self.changed, msg=self.out, warnings=self.warn, errors=self.err)
```

Currently, I am only getting back the "out" and "warn" and "err" of the first module that gets "process" called. Other modules are either not executed or not reported. I am expecting that exit_json is "exiting the entire Ansible run" and not just "the current module".

Am I correct? Is there a concept at play that I am not aware of? What is the best change here to ensure that the ansible "report" at the end of the run shows "all output of all instances"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For every task Ansible packages the module with all required libs and parameters before sending it to execution via SSH. So your main module (wrapper) should done all the job in a single run.

`exit_json` method [stops](https://github.com/ansible/ansible/blob/v2.3.1.0-1/lib/ansible/module_utils/basic.py#L1984) the whole process with `sys.exit(0)`, so when you call this method the first time your module's run is finished.

I'd recommend you to make one AnsibleModule class and a pack of helpers that return data to your parent module. Then you just combine all helpers' results into single object and flush it to stdout (with `exit_json`).

Comment: Thanks Konstantin, I agree. There are 2 possible approaches. 1) make a module with helpers that are gathered together to STDOUT as recommended and 2) Break apart the helpers into their own modules (essentially copying the contents of ctl.py onto the tail end of each helper class and moving the helper classes into the modules directory instead of having them all in module_utils. I'll try both and review with the users.